# How to call system.out.println from C++ via JNI?

Tags: java-native-interface

I'm trying to call `system.out.println` in JNI. How can I do that? Here is what I have so far:

```cpp
jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/lang/System");        
jmethodID constructor = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "out", "()Ljava.out.PrintStream;");
```

Comment: except for a masochistic exercise, there is no reason to call `system.out.println`: simply find the file descriptor used for `system.out` and use `fprintf()`!

Comment: Because System.out can be replaced with an arbitrary stream using System.setOut(), there may be no file descriptor.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a simple matter.
First, as you are doing, you have to get the java.lang.System class.
In that class is a static member "out", which is of type java.io.PrintStream.
You want to call the println() method of that class, which is heavily overloaded.
Simplify this by calling the String version of println().
All of this makes for a long-winded JNI transaction, but it goes something like this.
Caveat emptor: I have not compiled and run this code, but it is based on auto-generated JNI wrapper code that we use in production.

```cpp
// Get system class
jclass syscls = env->FindClass("java/lang/System");
// Lookup the "out" field
jfieldID fid = env->GetStaticFieldID(syscls, "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
jobject out = env->GetStaticObjectField(syscls, fid);
// Get PrintStream class
jclass pscls = env->FindClass("java/io/PrintStream");
// Lookup printLn(String)
jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(pscls, "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
// Invoke the method
jchar *cppstr = // make an array of jchar (UTF-16 unsigned short encoding)
jstring str = env->NewString(cppstr, length);
env->CallVoidMethod(out, mid, str);
```

Comment: I should also mention that there is a way to get form C++ strings encoded as ASCII or UTF8 more directly into the java jstring, by calling env->NewStringUTF(const char*)

Comment: do we need to release sth ?

Comment: @Raii usually not. NewString makes a "local ref", which is automatically disposed when your C++ code returns to the calling JNI frame.  However, you need to call DeleteLocalRef() explicitly if (1) you make a whole lot of them (2) your C++ code is not called from Java.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html and search for "DeleteLocalRef".  You may also need to convert the local ref to a global ref to keep it around longer.